# Error [ERR_WORKER_INVALID_EXEC_ARGV]: Initiated Worker with invalid NODE_OPTIONS env variable: --max-http-header-size= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Tags: webpack, jestjs, nrwl

I have below error with latest webpack where it breaks production builds
the versions i have are

```
webpack - 5.64.4
jest - 26.6.2
nrwl - 12.10.0
node - 14.16
```

i suspect my issue is due to this - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14859
but don't have exact point. my build started failing since 29th nov when this fix happen . this works fine in my local (mac os) but fail in test environment
any pointer will be helpful and if there is anything else needed please ask. i don't want to upgrade jest.

```
npm ls jest-worker

├─┬ @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.13
│ ├─┬ css-minimizer-webpack-plugin@3.0.2
│ │ └── jest-worker@27.3.1 
│ └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@5.1.4
│   └── jest-worker@27.3.1  deduped
├─┬ @nrwl/nest@12.10.0
│ └─┬ @nrwl/jest@12.10.0
│   ├─┬ @jest/reporters@27.2.2
│   │ ├─┬ jest-haste-map@27.4.2
│   │ │ └── jest-worker@27.4.2 
│   │ └── jest-worker@27.3.1  deduped
│   └─┬ jest-config@27.2.2
│     └─┬ jest-runner@27.4.2
│       └── jest-worker@27.4.2 
├─┬ @storybook/addon-essentials@6.3.12
│ └─┬ @storybook/addon-docs@6.3.12
│   ├─┬ @jest/transform@26.6.2
│   │ └─┬ jest-haste-map@26.6.2
│   │   └── jest-worker@26.6.2 
│   └─┬ @storybook/builder-webpack4@6.3.12
│     └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
│       └── jest-worker@26.6.2 
├─┬ @storybook/angular@6.3.12
│ └─┬ @storybook/core@6.3.12
│   └─┬ @storybook/core-server@6.3.12
│     └─┬ @storybook/manager-webpack4@6.3.12
│       └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@4.2.3
│         └── jest-worker@26.6.2 
├─┬ jest@26.2.2
│ └─┬ @jest/core@26.6.3
│   ├─┬ @jest/reporters@26.6.2
│   │ └── jest-worker@26.6.2 
│   ├─┬ jest-haste-map@26.6.2
│   │ └── jest-worker@26.6.2  deduped
│   ├─┬ jest-resolve-dependencies@26.6.3
│   │ └─┬ jest-snapshot@26.6.2
│   │   └─┬ jest-haste-map@26.6.2
│   │     └── jest-worker@26.6.2 
│   └─┬ jest-runner@26.6.3
│     └── jest-worker@26.6.2  deduped
└─┬ jest-cli@26.2.2
  └─┬ jest-config@26.6.3
    └─┬ @jest/test-sequencer@26.6.3
      ├─┬ jest-haste-map@26.6.2
      │ └── jest-worker@26.6.2 
      └─┬ jest-runner@26.6.3
        └── jest-worker@26.6.2

21:57:38  ERROR in 319.0a46e60283f8bec09734.manager.bundle.js from Terser
21:57:38  Error [ERR_WORKER_INVALID_EXEC_ARGV]: Initiated Worker with invalid NODE_OPTIONS env variable: --max-http-header-size= is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS
21:57:38      at new Worker (internal/worker.js:164:13)
21:57:38      at ExperimentalWorker.initialize (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js:149:20)
21:57:38      at new ExperimentalWorker (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/NodeThreadsWorker.js:145:10)
21:57:38      at WorkerPool.createWorker (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js:44:12)
21:57:38      at new BaseWorkerPool (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/jest-worker/build/base/BaseWorkerPool.js:127:27)
21:57:38      at new WorkerPool (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/jest-worker/build/WorkerPool.js:30:1)
21:57:38      at new Worker (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/jest-worker/build/index.js:167:26)
21:57:38      at getWorker (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:288:9)
21:57:38      at /bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:389:41
21:57:38      at /bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:23:31
21:57:38      at run (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:23:43)
21:57:38      at next (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:16:19)
21:57:38      at run (/bld/workspace/_Pipeline2_NX_Upgrade_forCypress@2/flex/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:31:3)
21:57:38      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
21:57:38      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
21:57:38      at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:66:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having the same node version on my pc and in the project.